# Add parameters to on("click") function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I made some markers on a map using

```
L.marker([42.76, 20.52], 5, {color: "blue"}).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Name: </b> My name<br /><b>Adress:</b> My adress<br /> <b>Description:</b>My description...").on("click", circleClick);
```

My circleClick function is the following:

```
function circleClick(e) {
app.getInfo(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);;}
```

I use this function to send the coordinates from `JavaScript` to `Java`. But now I want to add some parameters to my `circleClick` function. That's not a problem, I know how to do this. But I don't know how to call the function with parameters. I tried:

```
L.marker([42.76, 20.52],[...]).on("click", circleClick(e, parameter1, parameter2));
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me, how to specify the parameters at `.on("click", circleClick(...));`?

Comment: `.on("click", function(e){circleClick(e, parameter1, parameter2);});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
L.marker([42.76, 20.52],[...]).on("click", function(e) {
  circleClick(e, parameter1, parameter2);
});
```

From the jquery doc:
`The handler argument is a function (or the value false, see below), and is required unless you pass an object for the events argument.` What you're doing is calling the function in the `on()` method and not specifying the handler.

Comment: I added that. But my function still doens't work: `function circleClick(e, name, adress) {
app.getInfo(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng, name, adress);
}`

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8sqf63q/). If you're still having issues, then there might be something else wrong with the code. Try putting logs.

Comment: For the record, please note that Leaflet is not based on jQuery, even though it follows a similar API for attaching event listeners, like many other libraries.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind about the order of the parameters you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it to prepend parameters:

```
.on("click", circleClick.bind(null, parameter1, parameter2));
```

it will create function with prepended `parameter1`, `parameter2` so that the callback will be called like `circleClick(parameter1, parameter2, e)`